# How do I use sanitize to add links in plaintext?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to be able to add links in the body of a post (and not show it as plaintext). However, I do not want to allow any other HTML tags. Right now I have:

```
    sanitize @post.body, tags: %w(a), attributes: %w(href)
```

but this does not seem to work. 
I've also tried

```
    simple_format(@post.body).gsub(URI.regexp, '<a href="\0">\0</a>').html_safe
```

but that allows other HTML tags, which I do not want.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: More info needed. sanitize @post.body, tags: %w(a), attributes: %w(href) should work as expected

Comment: Sanitize should do what you want. If it's not working, we need more information to solve your problem

Comment: What sort of information?

Comment: Anything. What *is* being rendered? Nothing? the html markup? What's the content of @post.body that you're testing with?

Comment: Well as I mentioned it is being shown as plaintext, not a link. The string I am trying is: click to see this link about https://www.google.ca

Comment: What Version of Ruby/Rails?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.1 and ruby 2.1.2

Comment: Is the plaintext being shown including the markup, or is it sanitizing out the links despite your allowed tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94251/discussion-between-msanteler-and-user3477051).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the auto_link gem: auto_link(@comment.body)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby/Rails will not just identify a link in a string because it has http or www somwhere in it. Assuming you are getting the body of @post via a form, you need to wrap the input in some kind of WYSIWYG editor such as tinymce. Then, if the WYSIWYG editor saves the serialized input:

`click to see this link about <a href=\"https://google.ca\">google.ca</a>`

to the database, you can whitelist the `<a>` tag and `href` attribute so it actually generates a link

Comment: I don't understand what that means, can you include the raw value of @post.body in your question?

Comment: I hate conversing via comments. See my edited answer

Comment: @user3477051 does that make sense?